# Is this a capacitor? If nota.. what Is it?

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image].

This component was removed from a Nintendo 64 console PSU. I have no idea what it is. I thought it was a ceramic capacitor, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: It's either a 270 pF capacitor or a 270 volt varistor.

Comment: Test by applying 250V :D

Comment: I doubt it will work because it's already blown out hahaha!

Comment: To me it looks more like a ceramic capacitor than a varistor.  Can you show a picture of the circuit board where you removed it from.

Comment: Hopefully it is a varistor, because if that's a capacitor then something has gone terribly wrong.

Comment: The markings seem wrong for a capacitor.

Comment: It could be a varistor/transient voltage suppressor, or could be NTC termistor to limit inrush current of the PSU. All depends on circuitry from where you pulled it off. Do some reverse engineering of the primary (AC) side of your PSU, and post the schematics.

Comment: The markings look a bit wrong to me for it to be a varistor, a google search shows that they tend to have lots of text on them (safety markings).

Answer (score 2):

Since it came out of a power supply and is 'fat', it would be a NTC thermistor to limit in-rush current, usually placed right after the fuse. Varistors tend to be thin. If it is blown out then their is a shorted component downstream.

NTCs are not meant to be fuses or resettable fuses. They will blow if severely overloaded or have a latent failure in them. It may have been under rated for years of use. An MOV will not blow unless a lightning strike occurs. Normal line transients do not affect them. That is for the X and Y capacitors and common-mode choke to filter out.

NOTE: If it was a capacitor, it would need an X or Y label on it. Not absolutely certain of this part without research by the OP.

Comment: You certainly mean NTC, not PTC. https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2015/03/31/powertips-how-to-limit-inrush-current-in-an-ac-dc-power-supply

Comment: I have seen both NTC and PTC type used, but you are likely correct. It is not a resettable fuse like a PTC is. Right now it maybe a short circuit.